# jQuery fadeOut works but not fadeIn

Tags: jquery, fadein, slidedown

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/aaptz/15/) is my code on jsFiddle, when I try doing

```
$('#featuredStores').fadeOut(1000)
```

it works, but `.fadeIn()` doesn't work, Similarly when I use `.slideUp()` it works, but doesn't work when I use `.slideDown()`

what's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `slideDown()` shows the image. Considering your image is already shown when the DOM is rendered, there is nothing to slide down to. If you set the style as `display:none` then use `slideDown()`, it'll work.

Comment: Yes, it's the same for `fadeIn`